# wildfly standalone mode. Pros and cons between CLI deployment and using file-based deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

Wildfly server recommends the use of CLI management API over file system based deployments.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Application+deployment#Applicationdeployment-FileSystemDeployments

This is not a surprise or limited to just Wildfly. Other JEE servers also don't recommend file-based deployments for production. But what are the advantages and disadvantages of using one over the the other?

Answer (score 2):

I see two reasons to do this in a production system.

1. The server needs to use something like the [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to see if anything has changed.  While that might not be a huge overhead it is overhead nonetheless.
2. From a security perspective you need to be able to somehow transfer a war type file to the server.  This requires an O/S login that has permission to write to directories "owned" by the server.  That might mean that a user could maliciously or accidentally write to a configuration or other file that could affect the server.

On the other hand, if you are using the API to do this there is a different security aspect that is now controlled by Wildfly.  That takes configuration changes and management too.

I've seen this done both ways.  In a small environment with the server is locked down for just a few people it usually isn't a problem either way (though, again, the I/O hit could be decent).  But in a large environment with many applications potentially on the same instance the security aspect usually wins out.